# Serial port library/header file in C for WinCE

Tags: c, header, windows-ce, serial-port

I am a newbie in WinCE application programming. But the starting is not as smooth as expected. I could not find code examples, tutorials to learn from. I could not find a book on WinCE programming. Are all the libraries and header files for winCE same as for windows (WIN32)?

I am programming in C. I want to use serial port communication. But I could not find  the library for that. Which library/header file is used for serial port control/communication?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The required API calls are identical to desktop Win32 (with the eception that overlapped I/O is not supported).  You've start with CreateFile to open the port, SetCommSTate to adjust things like rate and parity, then use ReadFile and WriteFile for the I/O.

[Here's a CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/serial_com.aspx) that is very applicable.